# Use different name in asp:hiddenfield

Tags: asp.net

I have a for which is built within an ASP.net usercontrol.  This form is then used within a CMS as part of integration with a merchant gateway.  The gateway requires that a number of hiddenfields be passed in which is fine in the main however one of these needs to be called Profile.  The CMS I am using also defines a global variable called Profile and as such when I try and add a hidden field with this ID I get errors.

Is there a way of setting the 'name' property to Profile, and the ID to something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using plain HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" 
       name="Profile" 
       id="SomeId" 
       value="<%= Server.HtmlEncode("some value") %>" 
/>
```

Comment: Had tried this however had forgotten to remove runat=server - doh!